# blender datetime transformations

Tags: transforms

I need to move 2 objects based on datetime, lets call it position x. Once they're moved to position x, I'd want to refresh the script to get the current date, and only move the second object to the new position. I have a short script for the initial transformation, but I'm not sure how to solve the issue the most elegant way. -

```
import bpy
from datetime import datetime
then = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)        # Random date in the past
now  = datetime.now()                         # Now
duration = now - then                         # For build-in functions
duration_in_s = duration.total_seconds()
hours = divmod(duration_in_s, 3600)[0]
minutes = divmod(duration_in_s, 60)[0]   
days  = divmod(duration_in_s, 86400)[0]

cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
cube.location.x = minutes
```

Comment: From what you have written it is not clear what the question is. Are you searching for a way to run your script in regular intervals? Are you not sure how to perform the Transformation? Or is it a question on how to write better code? --- If its about running the script in intervals take a look at [Timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.app.timers.html) and/or [Handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html) . If it's about the transformations or the script style - there is nothing wrong with it. However you could change the `divmod(a, b)[0]` to `a // b`

Comment: sorry about that, let me try to re-phrase.

I have 2 objects. I want both to move to the current real world time, like the 'Cube' in the script. After they have their new transforms I want the second object to get the current updated real world time whenever I refresh the script, while I want the first one to remain at it's previously acquired position.

Comment: So its more a question on how to store if the one object has reached its endposition. -- This information has to be stored outside of the script as the script has no notion of the variables that where used the last time it was run. This can be achieved with [Custom Properties](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_quickstart.html#custom-properties) . Now you can just give the object a property (e.g. `obj['active'] = 0`) and only move it `if obj['active'] == 1`. A more robust way would be to use the `get` method as it provides a fallback (e.g `if obj.get('active', 1)`)

Comment: Ah, that's the one. I wasn't sure where to best store these things but it seems like custom properties will do the job. Thanks! Would I need to set that property manually though? The goal would be to get a timeline of some sorts with a start and end point, where the start point would be snapped to the current time once, and the end point would be updated based on current real world time either periodically or by refreshing manually.